# How to remove windows partition without having to erase the other one?

Tags: imac, windows, partition, fusion-drive

I have an imac late 2013 with a fusion drive. I've created a windows 10 partition and I'd like to delete it. I tried with bootcamp and disk utility but as you've probably heard before, it came up with that error  "the full size of the fusion drive is not available for partitioning".

I know that there are a lot of "solutions" out there but I couldn't find one that did not include to erase everything. I just want to erase the windows partition without having to erase the "macintosh hd" one.

Is there a genius out there who can help me ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try repairing disk, and repair disk permissions in Recovery (Command-R). Also delete the Bootcamp partition from Recovery since it tends to work better in terms of failing at the task.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue about 2 years ago and had to take it in to Apple to have mine fixed. The long and short of it is that your computers HD is really locked up and without the help of the Genius Bar it wont get fixed on your own. They had to work their magic for 5 days before they got it back to normal. Good luck.